# Python: how to return the length of the list passed to class as an argument with __len__()

Tags: python, class, oop

In the following code the class gets a list as an argument. Object has a "length" variable (length of that list)

The __ len __() method must return the value of "length"

```
class Gen:
    def __init__(self, lst, length ):
        self.lst = lst  # list
        self.length = length

    def show(self):
        print("List:", self.lst)

    def __len__(self):
        # will return 'length's value
        pass

x = Gen([1, 2, 3, 4])
x.show()
```

Comment: Return len(self.lst), what's the problem?

Comment: You've defined the `Gen` class to require two arguments, but you're only passing one.

Comment: the length variable remains unfilled. I need to use that variable too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this -

```
class Gen:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst  # list
        self.length = len(self.lst)

    def show(self):
        print("List:", self.lst)
        print("List Length:", self.length)

    def __len__(self):
        # will return 'length's value
        return self.length;

x = Gen([1, 2, 3, 4])
x.show()
```

Comment: is there a way to assign length of the list to "length" and return it in __ len __ itself?

Comment: @userr why do you want to return the custom length from __len__ function?

Comment: it's what the task says, i don't understand the point of it either.

Comment: it says "__ len __" must return "length" variable's value. causes me headache

Comment: I have edited the answer you want. __len__ will now return length variable value.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the length of your attribute 'lst' by using "self". Also, because length is based on your attribute, you could define it as a property (or not even declare it ...) :

```
class Gen:
  def __init__(self, lst):
    self.lst = lst  # list

  def show(self):
    print("List:", self.lst)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.lst)

x = Gen([1, 2, 3, 4])
x.show()
print(len(x)) # print 4
```

If you still want to use the length variable, then you can do this :

```
class Gen:
  def __init__(self, lst):
    self.lst = lst  # list
    self.length = len(lst)

  def show(self):
    print("List:", self.lst)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.length)

x = Gen([1, 2, 3, 4])
x.show()
print(len(x)) # print 4
```

Note that when you update the lst, the attribute length is not updated.

If you still want to have a length property (which feel javaey, because in python you use len), then you can do this:

```
class Gen:
  def __init__(self, lst):
    self.lst = lst  # list

  @property
  def length(self):
    return len(self.lst)

  def show(self):
    print("List:", self.lst)

  def __len__(self):
    return self.length

x = Gen([1, 2, 3, 4])
x.show()
print(len(x)) # print 4
```

Anyway, there are lot of variants for your question.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, the task says "__ len __ should return the "length" variable's value. Can't really understand how to do it